# OpenVPN connection issue on Azure VM

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, openvpn

I had many un succesfull attempts at installing openvpn access server on a VM but everytime the Issue is same. I connect to my VPN after installing but when I go to any website it says "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". Please tell me what is the Issue and I had install openvpn via this link: https://medium.com/@evgenijrenke/configure-openvpn-access-server-on-azure-6e6120bacddf. T had even tried to flush my Windows DNS but of no use.
Please Help!

Comment: Now, I tried to connect it with Windows 7 and it shows this Error on Chrome"dns_probe_finished_bad_config".

Comment: Please, share you Network Interface Card config and network topology and adresses. For the first look you need just to specify another DNS at your network interface card level, smth accessible like `8.8.8.8` , but it could be that your local addresses are in conflict with your VPN addresses.